# Need to get an answer in this format (1,1,1) in R

Tags: r, format, output

Have a code:

```
A<-numeric(9)
dim(A)<-c(3,3)
data.entry(A)
A
B<-numeric(3)
dim(B)<-c(3,1)
data.entry(B)
B
det(A)
solve(A)*det(A)
solve(A)
X<-solve(A,B)
X
```

The answer is:
1
1
1

X is Matrix
but i need (1,1,1) (not this "(1,1,1)"), please help!

Comment: I need to resolve the set of equations:
3x-3y+2z=2
4x-5y+2z=1
5x-6y+4z=3
Resolving by this formula: X=A^(-1)*B

An answer is (1,1,1)

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts for any reason.